# Drawing polygon on Esri map on chrome not working

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

Cannot draw polygon on chrome in esri Map

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Could someone please help it's chrome specific issue. In edge I can draw map
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZddT.png

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try to explain better the problem, what is the error?, when it is occurring? ..  add the error to the question .. Also add the code you are using (an extract with the main related parts is always better)

Comment: I was not able to draw polygon without any console error. It's resolved by upgrading esri version .